# Lubuntu 17.10 won't shutdown, but can reboot. end Kernel panic - not syncig: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000000

Tags: kernel, lubuntu, shutdown

everyone

I am currently having some problems with shutting down my Lubuntu 17.10, it hangs on the logo screen, but is able to reboot normally.

I have already tried a few tricks, but none of them seem to work. I have edited the grub file, excluding the 'quiet' and 'splash', and also edited the blacklist.conf file and also tried the shutdown command.

During the shutting down process, however, I realized that it hangs on **--[ end Kernel panic - not syncig: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000000**

I have searched, but do not know what to do to solve this problem. A little help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do not know why, but after the Lubuntu 18.04 update the problem has solved itself.